# Scss imports within Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have Next.js app, where I used scss and all the imports are at the top level scope of `_app.js`, as `import '../styles/styles.scss';`.

Is it lowering performance? because it should be import from the component as module.

If so, there is any major performance benefits if i will immigrate to css modules system?

Comment: Importing the Sass styles that way just makes them global styles, rather than local ones if you imported them as proper Sass modules on each component. Is there a reason you need to import your styles globally? If not, you might as well just use Sass modules.